# MacOS - Issue in opening MWB model files with MySQL Workbench 6.3

Tags: macos, mysql-workbench

**Issue:**

I cannot open mwb files in Mac but they are opened in MysqlWorkbench of Windows platform.

Versions are as follows:

- MacOs Sierra 10.12.5
- MysqlWorkbench 6.3

Error

- Cannot open document

> Note: I tried the older version of MySqlWorkbench but got the same
>   error.

*As I am new in Mac platform, I'd be grateful if anyone could assist me with their genuine solution.*

Comment: There must be more info in the error. Also see the log file (Help -> Show Log File) if you can spot anything that gives you a hint what's going wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your hint but I couldn't find any special info in the log. The same error msg is also seen in log file. Msg is as follows: 
**The file is not a Workbench document.**
As I told before the same model file is open successfully in Windows platform

Comment: Has this been copied as a text file from Win to Mac and got line breaks converted?

Comment: No, I have myModel.mwb file, it works on Windows but not in Mac. 
No copy-pasting the content, I mean exactly the same file.

Comment: I was mistaken. The file was corrupted. the size of file is too big and as a result when I get it with git clone from the repository, the file was not downloaded completely. So I used **git lfs pull** command to fetch the big files correctly. Now my issue has been solved.  
But I don't know why it worked correctly in Windows platform??

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue as following steps:

- Comparing file size in windows and mac versions of the file
- Mac version was corrupted
- As the model file was part of our git project, I tried to clone it one more time but again the same issue
- Downloading git-lfs
- try **git lfs pull** in the same path of cloned project in my local machine
- Then the model file was pulled one more time and this time the size was correct
- Last but not least, I could open it on MySQL Workbench in Mac